# Using collections to store objects to be processed in order

Tags: java, android, networking, collections, client-server

I'm currently having an issue where I am sending objects from one client to another over a network, and it seems that if the second object is sent instantly after, it seems to be overriding the first so it can therefore not be processed. However if the client emulators are both running on the same pc with the server this problem does not exist.

To solve my problem I'm thinking of using some form of collection such as a Deque to store the objects as they come in and then process them in order, removing them from the collection once they are processed.

I'm just wondering if this a good method of sorting my problem, or if anyone knows what could be causing this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put both objects in a `List` then send the whole list?

Comment: Do you need to process them in order?  (They may not _arrive_ in the same order they were sent, if you're sending them in some ad-hoc way.)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can you please be little clear?

Comment: Ok, ill try to expand a little, I'm basically drawing from one device to another, and sending the co-ordinates of the points in real time, the first point sent is not being processed when the android device is being run on another pc. I believe because it is being overridden before it can be processed.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't attach any code. I have no idea how you are currently processing your messages so I cannot guess what could be causing the issue.

Anyway, I can give you a suggestion. I think it's a rule of thumb that you need a queue to store a sequence of messages when you are going to process your messages **asynchronously**, otherwise you don't need a queue. Of course, this is not always the case, it still depends on your business logics.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a Deque to work as a buffer so that the objects were not overridden before they could be processed.